# WPF select listbox item on right click after scrolling listbox

Tags: wpf, listbox

I find some solution how select listbox item on right mouse button click, but any solution does not work after I scroll listbox. It possible select listbox on right mouse button, if I scroll also listbox? Any advance?

My code is here:

```
<ListBox Name="friendsListBox" 
         ItemsSource="{Binding}" 
         SelectedItem="Key"
         Style="{DynamicResource friendsListStyle}"
         PreviewMouseRightButtonUp="ListBox_PreviewMouseRightButtonUp"
         PreviewMouseRightButtonDown="ListBox_PreviewMouseRightButtonDown" 
         Grid.Row="1" MouseRightButtonDown="FriendsListBoxMouseRightButtonDown">
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
            <EventSetter Event="MouseDoubleClick" Handler="ListBoxItem_MouseDoubleClick"/>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ListBox.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu x:Name="FriendContextMenu">
            <MenuItem Name="SendRp" Header="Pošli Rp" Click="FriendContextMenuItem_Click" />
            <MenuItem Name="SendMsg" Header="Pošli poštu" Click="FriendContextMenuItem_Click"/>
            <MenuItem Name="DeleteFriend" Header="Vymaž" Click="FriendContextMenuItem_Click"/>
        </ContextMenu>
    </ListBox.ContextMenu>
</ListBox>
```

Code behind:

```
private void ListBox_PreviewMouseRightButtonDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    SelectItemOnRightClick(e);
    e.Handled = true;
}

private void ListBox_PreviewMouseRightButtonUp(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    SelectItemOnRightClick(e);
    FriendContextMenu.PlacementTarget = sender as UIElement;
    FriendContextMenu.IsOpen = true;
}

private void FriendsListBoxMouseRightButtonDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    SelectItemOnRightClick(e);
}

private void SelectItemOnRightClick(System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    Point clickPoint = e.GetPosition(friendsListBox);

    var listBoxItem =
           friendsListBox.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(0) as ListBoxItem;

    if (listBoxItem != null)
    {
        var nPotenialIndex = (int)(clickPoint.Y / listBoxItem.ActualHeight);

        if (nPotenialIndex > -1 && nPotenialIndex < friendsListBox.Items.Count)
        {
            friendsListBox.SelectedItem = friendsListBox.Items[nPotenialIndex];
        }
    }
}

private void ListBoxItem_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (friendsListBox.SelectedItem!=null)
    {
        var selectedFriend = (KeyValuePair<string, FriendData>)friendsListBox.SelectedItem;
        //MessageBox.Show(selectedFriend.Value.ProfilePhoto.UriSource.OriginalString);
        OpenWindow(FriendsData[selectedFriend.Value.Nick.ToLower()]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

To select an item on Right click, you can do this instead. It works with scroll

```
private void SelectItemOnRightClick(System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    Point clickPoint = e.GetPosition(friendsListBox);
    object element = friendsListBox.InputHitTest(clickPoint);
    if (element != null)
    {
        ListBoxItem clickedListBoxItem = GetVisualParent<ListBoxItem>(element);
        if (clickedListBoxItem != null)
        {
            friendsListBox.SelectedItem = clickedListBoxItem.Content;
        }
    }
}

public T GetVisualParent<T>(object childObject) where T : Visual
{
    DependencyObject child = childObject as DependencyObject;
    while ((child != null) && !(child is T))
    {
        child = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(child);
    }
    return child as T;
}
```

Comment: +1, that's roughly what I had in mind... Incidentally, it would also be pretty easy to refactor this code into an attached behavior, in order to make it easily reusable.

Comment: Meleak, thank you very much. Good sample. Have a nice weekend.